# angular 2 how to add a model within model

Tags: class, angular, typescript, model

I am getting a response json from API like below.

```
student: { 
           name : abc, 
           address : { 
                      city : ca, 
                      state:abc 
                      }, 
           age : 10 
         }
```

In order to bind this to a model, i need a model similar to this

```
class student {
      name:string;
      age:number;
      address:{ 
               city:string; 
               state:string
              }
       }
```

But when I bind the data to the above model. Address data is not binding to model. 
Please suggest the right way to write a model to bind the above data.

Comment: What do you mean by "binding data to a model"? What is your current code to "bind data to a model"? Do you mean that you want your data (`student`) to be an instance of the class?

Comment: high level binding code - studentobj = response.json(). response data is not stored in address properties

Comment: Ah ok. The "word" binding is misleading in Angular context. That's not what a binding is in Angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export class A {
  name:string;
  age:number;
  address:Adress;
   }


export class Adress  
           city:string; 
           state:string

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate an instance of the `Student` class, i.e.

```
class Student {
  // Define Student properties here
  name:string;
  age:number;
  // ...

  constructor(options) {
    // Set Student properties here
    this.name = options.name;
    this.age = options.age;
    this.address = options.address;
    // ...
  }
}

// Then:
const student = new Student(jsonData);
```